# Use a custom string to define symbolic variable

Tags: string, matlab, for-loop, symbolic-math

I am wondering how to make symbolic variables out of already defined strings. It actually will help us to make this code run:

```
N=2
for i=1:N
    syms sprintf('r%g',i)
end
```

This error is appeared after running it:

> Error using symfun.parseString (line 50)
>       Not a valid variable name.
>
> Error in syms (line 166)
>           [name, vars] = symfun.parseString(x);

I want it to create `r1` and `r2` as two symbolic variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because if you want to pass a string to `syms` you need to use the [function syntax rather than the command syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html). With your current syntax (command syntax), MATLAB is trying to create a symbolic variable named `'sprintf('r%g',i)'` and doesn't actually evaluate the `sprintf`.

Instead the function syntax should look like the following. Also, you should use `%d` in your format string to ensure that `i` is an integer otherwise it won't be a valid variable name.

```
syms(sprintf('r%d', i))
```